# Build tree from intended text string

Tags: python, django, recursion, tree

I have a model representing a node of a simple tree in django:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
```

And i have a document, that consists of a tree structure, intended with tabs, like this:

```
Level1.1
    Level2.1
    Level2.2
        Level3
Level1.2
```

When i parse this document, i have the following string:

```
'Level1.1\n\tLevel2.1\n\tLevel2.2\n\t\tLevel3\nLevel1.2'
```

How can i efficiently parse this string and create nodes? Result should be:

```
Node(name='Level1.1'), Node(name='Level2.1', parent=Node(previous node)) etc.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stack to keep track of parent nodes.

```
document = 'Level1.1\n\tLevel2.1\n\tLevel2.2\n\t\tLevel3\nLevel1.2'

stack = []  # keep track of ancestors ([0] - root, ..., [-1] - parent)
for line in x.splitlines():
    name = line.strip()
    level = line.count('\t')
    while len(stack) > level:
        stack.pop()
    node = Node(name=name, parent=stack[-1] if stack else None)
    node.save()
    stack.append(node)
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple, and no need for recursion! BTW, what's the purpose of prev_level variable?

Comment: @v01d, It's not required. removed. Thank you for pointing it out :)